# manipulating a Python list with treshold value

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need to make a function which would compare each value in a list and then set each value accordingly. Code follows:

```
actions = [0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.3, 0.8, 0, 0.00000000156]

def treshold(element, value):
    if element >= value:
        element == 1
    else: 
        element == 0

treshold(actions, 0.5)
```

This code however results in the following error:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'

I understand what this error says, however I do not know how to fix that.

Comment: Hint: Before knowing "how to fix that" think about what do you want the code to do (with that list) in human language first.

Comment: what you want to achive with  element == 1 (ignore that element is a list not a value)

Comment: I want that function to modify that array so that floats become integers.

Comment: Now, think about how can you modify the list? (alternatively just create a new one. Did you know about list comprehension?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compact way of doing this, as pointed out by  user202729 is with a list comprehension. The key is, you need to do this for each entry into the list. If you want to run it on the whole list at once, you could consider using numpy

```
actions = [0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.3, 0.8, 0, 0.00000000156]

def treshold(element, value):
    thresholded_list = [int(a>=value) for a in actions]
    return thresholded_list
```

this function is essentially a shorthand for

```
def treshold_long(element_list, value):
    thresholded_list = []
    for element in element_list:
        if element >= value:
            thresholded_list.append(1)
        else: 
            thresholded_list.append(0)
    return thresholded_list
```

Comment: The first version need `int(a>=value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user202729 I have discovered list comprehensions.

```
actions = [0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.3, 0.8, 0, 0.00000000156] 
treshold = 0.5      

actions = [1 if i>=treshold else 0 for i in actions]
print(actions)
```

This basically solves my problem. I also thank to user3235916 for a valid function.